# Массовое переименование файлов рекурсивно

Tags: windows-10

Есть много документов. Их расширения надо менять.

`FOR /R %x IN (*.0) DO ren "%x" *.pdf`

Это хорошо справляется. Но мне надо менять только те файлы, что бы в родительская папка название содержал в конце ".pdf"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не обязательно средствами Win, может TC, или проги какие есть.

Answer (score 1):

может что-то такое? (не проверял)

```
FOR /R %p IN (*.pdf) DO FOR %x IN (%p\*.0) DO ren "%x" *.pdf
```